# Mousedown is not triggering from a checkbox in modal popup to an outside popup button

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, event-handling, mousedown

The modal popup is a drupal dialogbox which is coming inside an iframe. I need to trigger mousedown on a submit button which is outside iframe when checkboxes are clicked in popup. I wrote the below jquery, but the button is not affecting.

```
$('#modal-popup .form-boolean--type-checkbox').click(() => {
   let body = $(window.parent.document.body);
   console.log(body);         
   body.find('[name="add_more_button"]').mousedown();
});
```

`$(window.parent.document.body).find('[name="add_more_button"]').mousedown();` works in the console but not from jQuery. Why is this?

Comment: Does the `[name="add_more_button"]` element exist in the DOM when you call `mousedown()`?

Comment: Yes, it is present.

Comment: What do you see in the console when you run this line in your jQuery event handler: `console.log(body.find('[name="add_more_button"]').length)`

Comment: I get '1' in console.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution after hours of research. From iframe we can call a function of parent window. I used below code and working fine.

```
$('#modal-popup .form-boolean--type-checkbox').click(() => {
    window.parent.parentFunction();
 });

 window.parentFunction = function(){
   $('[name="add_more_button"]').mousedown();
 }
```

I used separate function for triggering the button and used **window.FuntionName** name for this.
From iframe popup, I called this function to trigger mousedown using **window.parent.FunctionName()**